# Google Spreadsheets - change background color in while loop

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to change the backgroundcolor of one of my cells every 2 seconds while a status is '6 - aanvraag'.

However when I execute the script below, it will only make it white when the script has been executed, and it never becomes red.

Can anyone help me with this.

```
  var eenheidColom = sheet.getRange('A7');
  var status = spreadsheet.getRange('C5').getValue();

  while (status == '6 aanvraag') {
    eenheidColom.setBackgroundRGB(255,0,0)
    Utilities.sleep(2000);
    eenheidColom.setBackgroundRGB(255,255,255)
    status = spreadsheet.getRange('C5').getValue();
  }
}
```

Comment: It might help you [SpreadsheetApp.flush()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app?hl=ru#flush())

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Answer:

*You need to force push changes to your sheet between the two calls to set the background colour.*

#### More Information:

Often times, operations to Sheets are acted upon in batches, so visual changes might not be seen. You can force all pending actions through however, by making a call to [`SpreadsheetApp.flush()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app?hl=ru#flush()).

#### Code Changes:

I made a couple of small code changes to make your loop more efficient, in addition to the `flush()` call:

```
const eenheidColom = sheet.getRange('A7')
const cell = spreadsheet.getRange('C5')
let status = cell.getValue()

while (status === '6 aanvraag') {
  eenheidColom.setBackgroundRGB(255, 0, 0)
  SpreadsheetApp.flush()
  Utilities.sleep(2000)

  eenheidColom.setBackgroundRGB(255, 255, 255)
  SpreadsheetApp.flush()
  Utilities.sleep(2000)

  status = cell.getValue()
}
```

#### Visual Example:

[image]